# Ravendb Spatial search with ORderBydistance

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I need to get the nearest 15 locations from a point.I have first created a Spatial Index and then Im trying to order the result by distance by calling OrderByDistance method but Im getting this exception

> Cannot execute query method 'OrderByDistance'. Field 'spatial.point(Latitude, Longitude)' cannot be used when static index 'SupplierCoordinatesLookup' is queried. 
>   Dynamic spatial fields can only be used with dynamic queries, for static index queries please use valid spatial fields defined in index definition.

This is my query

```
List<SupplierCoordinates> suplierCoordinates = _documentSession
           .Query<SupplierCoordinates, SupplierCoordinatesLookup>()
            .Spatial(
                "Coordinates",
                criteria => criteria.WithinRadius(0, supplierCoordinates.Latitude, supplierCoordinates.Longitude))
            .OrderByDistance(factory => factory.Point(x => x.Latitude, x => x.Longitude), supplierCoordinates.Latitude, supplierCoordinates.Longitude)
            .Take(15)
            .ToList();
```

and here is the code for my index

```
Map = collection => from doc in collection
                            select new
                            {
                                Coordinates = CreateSpatialField(doc.Latitude, doc.Longitude)
                            };
        Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
    _documentSession
           .Query<SupplierCoordinates, SupplierCoordinatesLookup>()
            .OrderByDistance("Coordinates", supplierCoordinates.Latitude, supplierCoordinates.Longitude)
            .Take(15)
            .ToList();
```

Your index already contains points, so you only have to supply a field from index ("Coordinates") to your query